# Combining QueryDSL with Hibernate Search and Lucene

Tags: hibernate, lucene, querydsl, hibernate-search

I configured Hibernate Search with Apache Lucene to more easly search enitites by given coordinates. Now I'm wondering how I can add more criteria to search entities. I'm also using Spring Data project and Query DSL. I'm trying to use `Predicate` class from QueryDSL to keep my app consistent. There is any posibility to do this?

My Place.class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Indexed
@Spatial
public class Place implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8379536848917838560L;
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "place_id")
    private Long id;

    //...
    @Longitude
    private Double lng;

    @Latitude
    private Double lat;
    //...
    }
```

My repository class

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
EntityManager em;

@Override
@Transactional
public List findAll(Coordinates coordinates, Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, int maxDistance) {

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

    QueryBuilder builder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Place.class).get();

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = builder
            .spatial()
            .within(maxDistance, Unit.KM)
            .ofCoordinates(coordinates)
            .createQuery();

    FullTextQuery jpaQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Place.class);
    return jpaQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're not asking about combining multiple full-text queries with a Boolean Query - as I hope the docs have enough examples about that - but that you're asking about adding SQL based restrictions.

In practice it is possible to restrict a `FullTextQuery` further by applying a `Criteria`, however while this seems to work, this feature was not intentional (fun story behind this!), is poorly tested and is not efficient at all: avoid if possible. It wasn't removed as some people really like it.

You can find an example - and warnings about the limitations - in Example "5.12. Specifying FetchMode on a query":
 - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.6/reference/en-US/html_single/

A better solution is to run a full-text-query by restricting only on indexed fields, so that the query can be fully resolved by Lucene only.

Sometimes it helps to encode additional fields in the index, somehow "pre-tagging" Lucene Document which you want to match. This is where people need to get a bit creative, and you might write some custom `FieldBridge` and `ClassBridge` implementations.

Then you apply a [Full-Text Filter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-filter), or combine multiple queries with boolean queries: see section "5.1.2.8. Combining queries".

Comment: I was looking way to combine lucene query with my own sql queries/criteria, because I feel more confident with sql rather than lucene, but thank you. I've done what i want and it works brilliant.